# Trying to combine and/or arguments for MySQL query

Tags: mysql, pdo, modx

I am attempting to query a MYSQL table with three 'scenarios' for finding objects. While I have successfully broken these into three separate queries I feel there has to be a 'better and faster' way to sift through the data. However, when I combine like below, I do not find any objects matching the query. This is using xPDO within MODx. The failed attempt is immediately below:

```
$orders=$modx->newQuery('Orders');
$orders->where(array(
    array( //scenario #1
        'Orders.start_date:<=' => $rentalDate->end_date,
        'AND:Orders.start_date:>=' => $rentalDate->start_date
    ),
    array( //scenario #2
         'OR:Orders.end_date:<=' => $rentalDate->end_date,
         'AND:Order.start_date:>=' => $rentalDate->start_date
    ),
    array( //scenario #3
        'OR:Orders.end_date:>=' => $rentalDate->start_date,
        'AND:Orders.end_date:<=' => $rentalDate->end_date       
    )
    ));
$conflictingOrders = $modx->getCollection('Orders',$orders);
```

However, if I run each scenario separately, it does pick up the objects correctly. Example:

```
$s1Query=$modx->newQuery('Orders');
$s1Query->where(array(array('Orders.start_date:<=' => $rentalDate->end_date,'AND:Orders.start_date:>=' => $rentalDate->start_date)));
$s1Results=$modx->getCollection('Orders',$s1Query);
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong in the first code? Please let me know if any further information is needed. Cheers!

Helpful doc:http://rtfm.modx.com/xpdo/2.x/class-reference/xpdoquery/xpdoquery.where

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array scenarios in your code are being treated as AND conditions when listed in the `$orders->where()` method.

Try this:

```
$orders = $modx->newQuery('Orders');
$orders->where(array(
    'Orders.start_date:<=' => $rentalDate->end_date,
    'AND:Orders.start_date:>=' => $rentalDate->start_date
));
$orders->orCondition(array( //scenario #2
    'Orders.end_date:<=' => $rentalDate->end_date,
    'AND:Order.start_date:>=' => $rentalDate->start_date
));
$orders->orCondition(array( //scenario #3
    'Orders.end_date:>=' => $rentalDate->start_date,
    'AND:Orders.end_date:<=' => $rentalDate->end_date
));

// uncomment the following lines to see the raw query generated
// $orders->prepare();
// print_r($orders->toSql());

$conflictingOrders = $modx->getCollection('Orders',$orders);
```

Comment: Thank you for added help. That `toSql` is magic, a real game changer. I applied the scenarios as `orCondition` and the query worked as hoped. Thanks again. Cheers.